# How to test console.log output using Jest or other Javascript Testing Framework?

Tags: testing, asynchronous, logging, jestjs

I have a function that runs asynchronously, console logging the numbers 1 through 5 in order after a random setTimeout. I want to write a test for this function using Jest. How do I write one that tests that the console.log is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can using `jest.fn`.

Here is an example:

File `hello.js`

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

File `hello.test.js`

```
let outputData = "";
storeLog = inputs => (outputData += inputs);
test("console log Hello World", () => {
  console["log"] = jest.fn(storeLog);
  require("./hello.js");
  expect(outputData).toBe("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: you should store the original console.log function in a variable and after the test finished restore the original console.log, if not this might mess with other possible tests

Comment: That answer shows how to check whether `console.log` is called, not the actual content in stdout, it is not the same, unfortunately.