# How to use Jest to test a console.log that uses chalk?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, chalk

Writing a Node CLI in my module I have a `console.log` with [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk), example:

```js
console.log(
  chalk.green(`${delta}:`),
  chalk.white(`\nAPI: ${apiPath}`),
)
```

when I run a Jest code coverage `--coverage` I'm reminded that I didn't have a test so I wrote:

```js
test(`Test console log`, async () => {
  await mod(params)
  await expect(console.log).toBe(`${delta}:\nAPI: ${apiPath}`)
})
```

but I get an error of:

```
Expected: "string"
Received: [Function log]
```

Second attempt from research I tried:

```js
test(`Test console log`, async () => {
  await mod(params)
  await expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${delta}:\nAPI: ${apiPath}`)
})
```

but I get an error of:

```
Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function log]
```

Research:

- [How do I test a jest console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096093/how-do-i-test-a-jest-console-log)
- [Console.log statements output nothing at all in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695717/console-log-statements-output-nothing-at-all-in-jest)
- [How to test console.log output using Jest or other Javascript Testing Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890836/how-to-test-console-log-output-using-jest-or-other-javascript-testing-framework)

With Jest how can I test a `console.log` that uses chalk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// newTest.js

const chalk = require('chalk');

function functionUnderTest(delta, apiPath) {
  console.log(chalk.green(`${delta}:`), chalk.white(`\nAPI: ${apiPath}`));
}

module.exports = functionUnderTest;


// newTest.test.js

const functionUnderTest = require('./newTest');
const chalk = require('chalk');

jest.mock('chalk', () => ({
  green: jest.fn(),
  white: jest.fn(),
}));

it('calls console.log and chalk.blue with correct arguments', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'log');
  chalk.green.mockReturnValueOnce('test-blue');
  chalk.white.mockReturnValueOnce('test-white');

  functionUnderTest(5, 'my-path');

  expect(chalk.green).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5:');
  expect(chalk.white).toHaveBeenCalledWith('\nAPI: my-path');
  expect(global.console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test-blue', 'test-white');

  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

To access global objects you have to use global context ([Jest: how to mock console when it is used by a third-party-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223963/jest-how-to-mock-console-when-it-is-used-by-a-third-party-library)).
You do that by spying `log` method of the `console` global object.

The important part regarding the test itself is that there are 2 dependencies that need to be mocked, the `console.log` (which is done in the spy) and the `chalk` (which i'm doing with the `jest.mock`) where i say that it has a property named `green` which is a mocked function (and `white`). Here what should be tested is that the `console.log` prints what is returned from the `chalk.green` call. So assigned a dummy string to be the result of the `chalk.green` call (`test-result`) and assert that `console.log` is called with that same string. The same for the `white` mock function.